# How to list oneToMany using ZF2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I am trying to create listAction() to list all data from an Entity. I have used the example listed in [Update two tables from one form with ZF2 and Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648186/update-two-tables-from-one-form-with-zf2-and-doctrine/) and [Hydrator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md) to create my study case.

I am able to list the parent data but the data from child entity I just dont know how.

Just don't  know how to create the list.phtml do show the child data entities.

There is an example anywhere?

**ProfileController.php**

```
public function updateAction()
{

    // Verificar se existe parâmetro passado na rota
    $id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

    // Se não existe parâmetro, redirecionar para lista
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
            $this->route,
            array(
                'controller' => $this->controller,
                'action' => 'list')
        );
    }

    // Get your ObjectManager from the ServiceManager
    $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    // Create the form and inject the ObjectManager
    $form = new PerfilUpdate($objectManager);

    // Buscar dados na entidade and bind it to the form
    $perfil = $this->getEm()->find($this->entity, $id);
    $form->bind($perfil);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Save the changes
            $objectManager->flush();

            // Redirecionar para lista de perfis
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
                $this->route,
                array(
                    'controller' => $this->controller,
                    'action' => 'list')
            );

        }
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form,
        'id' => $id,
    );
}
```

**update.phtml**

```
<?php
$title = $this->translate('Editar Perfil');
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <?php echo $title ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $form = $this->form;

    $form->setAttribute('action',
        $this->url(
            'tenil-user/default',
            array(
                'controller' => 'profile',
                'action' => 'update',
                'id' => $this->id
            ))
    );

    $form->prepare();

    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
    ?>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <?php

        $id = $form->get('perfil')->get('id');
        echo $this->formHidden($id);

        $security = $form->get('security');
        echo $this->formElement($security);

        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        $nome = $form->get('perfil')->get('nome');
        echo $this->formLabel($nome);
        echo '<div class="col-md-10">';
        echo $this->formInput($nome);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        $sobrenome = $form->get('perfil')->get('sobrenome');
        echo $this->formLabel($sobrenome);
        echo '<div class="col-md-10">';
        echo $this->formInput($sobrenome);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        $apelido = $form->get('perfil')->get('apelido');
        echo $this->formLabel($apelido);
        echo '<div class="col-md-10">';
        echo $this->formInput($apelido);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <?php
                $submit = $form->get('submit');
                $submit->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-default');
                echo $this->formSubmit($submit);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php


    echo $this->form()->closeTag();

    foreach ($form as $element) {
        echo $this->formElementErrors($element);
    }
?>

</div>
```

When I submit the form, whith the changes, the `$id` param aways is set to null, then `if (!$id)` is true. So the data is never updated.

Comment: Please add some details to your question. What did you try? What is not working? And share some code you are using... Like this no one will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Hi @Wilt, I`ve added some code to my question, where I think the problem is.